# matlab scripts don't accept functions?

Tags: matlab

I've got some experience using octave. However, matlab is acting very differently. 
I've got this simple script:

```
function y=test(x)
    y=x*10;
end

a=test(10);
```

When I run it (that green 'play'-arrow in the GUI) it gives me the following error:

```
Error: File: TESTFILE.m Line: 5 Column: 1
This statement is not inside any function.
 (It follows the END that terminates the definition of the function "bla".)
```

What's wrong? Can't I just run a scipt where I use my own functions next to code not within a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style of your code works in Python as well, but not in MATLAB. The error is giving you the answer `This statement is not inside any function`. You have three following solutions:

**1-** Either make a main function (this is in the same m-file)

```
function a=main()
    a=test(10);
end


function y=test(x)
    y=x*10;
end
```

**2-** Or save the function as `test.m` and use the last line to call your function from another script or from the command line.

**3-** You can also have nested functions (all in the same m-file):

```
function a=main()
    a=test(10);

    function y=test(x)
        y=x*10;
    end
end
```

Find very useful documentation and examples [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: option 1 is not working:Not enough input arguments.
Error in mytest (line 2)
    y=x*10; Option 3 is working...very redundant though

Comment: because you do not see the output. add `a` as output and give it inputs if you like. The function here has no input argument but you can add by yourself. It 100% works by its current form though.

Comment: has it always been like that in matlab? octave accepts my code and I dont see any reason why matlab should not. Is there a reason at all?

Comment: The reason is when you make a function, MATLAB does not let you add some code outside of that function, unless that is another function. As I remember from 1994 MATLAB was like this, although we did not have nested functions then :)

Comment: ok. so i guess its also not possible to define functions in the command window?

Comment: It is not `Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.` But I do not see a good reason that somebody wants to define a function in the command line that might be cleared out or overwitten in and instance.